# Android Webview "swiperefreshlayout" keep spinning, how to stop it?

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

I am trying to refresh webview using `SwipeRefreshLayout`. I don't know how to stop refresh circle. I even don't know its refreshing webview or not.

Here is `content_main` the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.logitex.webviewandrefresh.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh">

    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the `MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: So did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
  swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

  WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
  }


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
         swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
      myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
      swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
}
```

Comment: I am just a beginner. Please tell me in easy words. Or step by step.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a listener so that when the `WebView` is finished loading, you can get a callback. So in your `onCreate` function do this.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); 
    }
});
```

In your `onRefresh` function, you need to remove this line.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Because, you are assigning a new `WebViewClient` here which overrides the previous one that you've set in your `onCreate` function.

So finally, you `MainActivity` will look like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
    }
}
```

Got this working in my side. Cheers!

Comment: Please see the updated answer and accept it its helpful :)